# Why is schema owned by default postgres and not my account?

Tags: postgresql

Why does this file create a schema with the owner being `postgres` and not `me` and when I try to list all relations

I don't get any entries where the schema is `db_schema`

and when I try to view the table using `\d db_schema.item` I get the error
`Did not find any relations named "db_schema.item"`

`create_db.sql`

```
CREATE USER me WITH PASSWORD '123';
CREATE DATABASE d_b WITH me;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE d_b TO me;

CREATE SCHEMA db_schema;

SET search_path to db_schema;

CREATE TABLE db_schema.items (
    id serial,
    str text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE db_scheme.thing (
    id serial, 
    uuid integer,
    item_id integer not null references db_schema.item(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I tried using `SET search_path TO db_schema;` and viewing the table  but I got the same error

**Update**

when logging in using `psql -h localhost -U me d_b` and then using `\dn` I only get one schema listed

```
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
```

Comment: Because you did not switch the user to `me` after createing the user and the database.

Comment: The user "postgres" created the schema (and other objects) and you didn't change the ownership.

Comment: @FrankHeikens how do i change the ownership of the schema ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried to use `\c me d_b` but this results in a connection error

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA db_schema OWNER TO me;
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-alterschema.html

Comment: 1) There is only `public` schema in `d_b` because after `CREATE DATABASE d_b WITH me;` you did not connect to `d_b` so everything after that was added to whatever database you where in. 2) It should be `\c d_b me` per [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html): *\c or \connect [ -reuse-previous=on|off ] [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] | conninfo ]* 3) You need to spend some time reading the docs to get a handle on the basics.